# Why the heck is phpinfo version still stuck at 7.1 after update?

Tags: php, apache, command-line, terminal, apache2

Running phpinfo() shows the version to be 7.1.23 but php -v shows the version to be 7.3.10. I have this line (`LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`) uncommented after running `sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf` on Terminal. What am I possibly doing wrong here?? Please help, I've been stuck at this for the past 12 hours, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: did you make sure you don't have two separate versions of php installed ?

Comment: this might help, https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php/1190483

Comment: @OmarAbbas This location (`/usr/local/bin/php`) shows php to be version 7.3.10, and this location (`/usr/bin/php`) shows php to be version 7.1.23. Idk how to set the default to be the 7.3.10 one.

Comment: @OmarAbbas But I read that question a dozen times and went through the same steps as followed in that link - nothing, it did not help at all

Comment: which version of php do you want to use ?

Comment: @OmarAbbas version 7.3.10

Comment: @OmarAbbas I got it to work nvm

Comment: glad it worked, what made it work ? please answer your own questions so that other user can also benefit from it.